# Why does "vite build --watch" see changes on .vue files?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, laravel-9, inertiajs

i have created a new Laravel 9, Inertia, Vue3 project.
From the "old" laravel i know the "npm run hot"-script ("hot": "mix watch --hot").
Due to Laravel 9 runs with Vite, you should use the "vite build --watch" script to continuously compiling your code.
This works pretty fine except the .vue files. I have created a "Demo.vue"-Site and when i making changes there, nothing "recompiles" or is changing in the browser. Only when I change other files, the browser view changes to new vue-file.

I already have tried to change the "watch" settings in the vite.config.js, without further success.
Now I have rollback these changes and my vite.config.js looks like this

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import FullReload from 'vite-plugin-full-reload';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        FullReload(),
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Do i have to configure anything else in the vite config or somewhere else?

Comment: If you have a new `.vue` file, I guess you need to restart the server. Maybe only the current files at the time of launching the server are being watched.

Comment: But it's not that much about new `.vue` files, it's more about updating existing one. I don't want to restart the server every time i change something. And the fact that changes in the vue file will be updated, if i change something in the "app.js" file, showing that it's not an technical issue, that is not possible to recomplie automatically after changes have been done

Comment: This is more of a Laravel issue because it's work well with a vanilla Vue3 app.

Comment: Do you have any idea of a way to fix that? Sadly i don't have much experience with vite

Comment: That should work well by default on Vite's side. Check on Laravel's community.

Comment: write folders you need to ferresh:
refresh:  [
                'resources/css/**',
                'resources/site/**',
                'resources/site/components/**',
                'resources/**',
            ],